# Selecting similar objects

Tags: combinatorics, logic, combinations

Say I have a set of $x$ things of which $A$ are the same kind, $B$ are the same kind, and so on...
$x=A+B+...$
So I have to find the number of ways in which a selection can be made, the general formula given is
$(A+1)(B+1)...-1$
Can anyone please explain how this is the case?
I understand the formula in case it was permutations (which is $\frac{x!}{A!B!...}$) but can't figure out the logic for the selection formula.

Comment: I’m assuming you’re told you must choose at least $1$ object.  Your set is determined by the number of objects of type $A, B, \ldots$.  You can choose $0, 1, 2, \ldots, A$ of the first type.  Do you see what’s going on now?

Comment: Pick how many objects of the first kind.  There are $A+1$ options... ranging from having selected none, selecting one of them, selecting two of them, and so on up to having selected all $A$ of them.  Next, pick how many objects of the second kind you selected and so on.  Presumably you didn't want to count the outcome of having selected none at all overall which is present in the formula you cite as the $-1$ at the end.